# Error creating bean with name 'loginServer': Failed to introspect bean class

Tags: spring, spring-boot

This is my code

```
@Path("/umm")

public class LoginServer {
    private transient Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
    @Context
    HttpServletRequest contextRequest;

@Path("/basicLogin")
@POST
public @ResponseBody Response login(@RequestBody(required = true) LoginRequest loginRequest){
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    LoginResponse loginResponse = new LoginResponse();
    try {
        LoginClient loginClient = new LoginClient();
        loginResponse = loginClient.login(loginRequest,contextRequest);

        return null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
        return null;
    }       
}
```

I run it and didn't get any error but when I use "Postman" for test Path I get 404 Error

[404 ERROR in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGRbh.jpg)

But when I try to replace @RestController @PostMapping @RequestMapping like this.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/umm")
public class LoginServer {
    private transient Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
    @Context
    HttpServletRequest contextRequest;
```

I get this log error!

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginServer': Failed to introspect bean class [escf.api.login.LoginServer] for lookup method metadata: could not find class that it depends on; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/Response
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:269) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1091) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at escf.UMMOutboundserviceApplication.main(UMMOutboundserviceApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/Response
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
... 23 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.core.Response
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:151) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
... 30 common frames omitted
```

I don't need to get that error and 404 errorr.
...............................................

Comment: A full log would be much helpful

Comment: I change return type from Response to void or anything else it's work but still getting error code 400 in postman with correct JSON format.

Comment: Did you add the dependency to your pom.xml?

Comment: Yes, I did before.

Comment: Your BeanCreationException is caused by an ClassNotFoundException:

    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.core.Response

Did you really add that artifact to your pom.xml?

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm import 'Produces' and 'MediaType' from javax.ws.rs dependency and didn't get any error.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring, you must use the annotations [@*Mapping](http://appsdeveloperblog.com/spring-mvc-postmapping-getmapping-putmapping-deletemapping/), [@Rest/Controller](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller) and [@Autowired](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire) for Dependency Injection. Otherwise it cannot work.

Comment: I already use @ResController but I get this error "Error creating bean with name 'loginServer': Failed to introspect bean class""

Comment: The LoginServer cannot be used from Spring because it is not a bean. You must annotate this class with Controller or RestController. Otherwise this class is not considered.

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

As it is not able to find javax.ws.rs.core.Response so it throws ClassNotFoundException